# Variable referencing. How to create arrays getting their names from elements of another array

Tags: powershell

This is as simplified version of what I'd like to achieve... I think it's called 'variable referencing'

I have created an array containing the content of the folder 'foo'

```
$myDirectory(folder1, folder2)
```

Using the following code:

```
$myDirectory= Get-ChildItem ".\foo" | ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName}
```

I'd like to create 2 arrays named as each folders, with the contained files.

```
folder1(file1, file2)
folder2(file1, file2, file3)
```

I tried the following code:

```
foreach ($myFolder in $myDirectory) {
    ${myFolder} = Get-ChildItem ".\$myFolders" | forEach-Object {$_.BaseName}
}
```

But obviously didn't work.

In bash it's possible create an array giving it a variable's name like this:

```
"${myForder[@]}"
```

I tried to search on Google but I couldn't find how to do this in Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it at the end:

```
# Create an array containing all the folder names
$ToursArray = Get-ChildItem -Directory '.\.src\panos' | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
# For each folder...
$ToursArray | ForEach-Object {
    # Remove any variable named as the folder's name. Check if it exists first to avoid errors
    if(Test-Path variable:$_.BaseName){ Remove-Variable -Name $_.BaseName }
    $SceneName=Get-ChildItem ".\.src\panos\$_\*.jpg"
    # Create an array using the main folder's name, containing the names of all the jpg inside 
    New-Variable -Name $_ -Value ($SceneName | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName)
}
```

And here it goes some code to check the content of all the arrays:

```
# Print Tours information
Write-Verbose "Virtual tours list: ($($ToursArray.count))"
$ToursArray | ForEach-Object {
Write-Verbose "  Name: $_"
Write-Verbose "    Scenes: $($(Get-Variable $_).Value)"
```

}

Output:

```
VERBOSE:   Name: tour1
VERBOSE:     Scenes: scene1 scene2
VERBOSE:   Name: tour2
VERBOSE:     Scenes: scene1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myDirectory = "c:\temp" 
Get-ChildItem $myDirectory | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
        Remove-Variable -Name $_.BaseName
        New-Variable -Name $_.BaseName -Value (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select -ExpandProperty Name)
    }
```

I think what you are looking for is `New-Variable`. Cycle through all the folders under `C:\temp`. For each folder make a new variable. It would throw errors if the variable already exists. What you could do for that is remove a pre-exising variable. Populate the variable with the current folders contents in the pipeline using `Get-ChildItem`. The following is a small explanation of how the `-Value` of the new variable is generated. **Caveat** `Remove-Variable` has the potiential to delete unintended variables depending on your folder names. Not sure of the implications of that.

```
Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

The value of each custom variable is every file ( not folder ). Use `-ExpandProperty` to just gets the names as strings as supposed to a object with `Name`s.

**Aside**

What do you plan on using this data for? It might just be easier to pipe the output from the `Get-ChildItem` into another cmdlet. Or perhaps create a custom object with the data you desire.

**Update from comments**

```
$myDirectory = "c:\temp" 
Get-ChildItem $myDirectory | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Hotel = $_.BaseName
            Rooms = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select -ExpandProperty Name)
        }

    }
```

You need to have at least PowerShell 3.0 for the above to work. Changing it for 2.0 is easy if need be. Create and object with hotel names and "rooms" which are the file names from inside the folder. If you dont want the extension just use `BaseName` instead of `Name` in the select.

Comment: The data is to create some xml files to use in a website. Basically each folder is a hotel, and their content (jpg files) are rooms. At this stage, I think there must be a better and easier way to do this. Maybe an array containing 2 arrays (one for each hotel), and each of this arrays contains the room names.

Comment: @RafaelGP Updated answer with simple change